# ReadFileEx completion callback gives wrong number of bytes when called from C#

Tags: c#, winapi, interop, pinvoke

I'm using pinvoke to call [ReadFileEx](http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/kernel32/ReadFileEx.html) from C#. I have similar code working in C++.

My callback delegate is:

```
[UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.Winapi)]
public delegate void ReadFileCompletionDelegate(
  uint dwErr, 
  uint cbBytesRead, 
  ref OVERLAPPED overlapped);
```

1. I zero out an OVERLAPPED structure before calling.
2. I call `CreateFile` with `Overlapped | NoBuffering`.
3. Next I call `ReadFileEx` passing my overlapped structure and callback.
4. Finally, I use `SleepEx(INFINITE, true)` to wait

My callback is called, so that's a good start. However, it behaves strangely.

With a debugger attached, the `cbBytesRead` parameter is always 768 - despite the buffer size I pass to `ReadFileEx`.

Without a debugger attached, `cbBytesRead` is always `0xFFFFFFFF`, or whatever I pass to my `SleepEx` call! If I call `SleepEx(1337, true)` my cbBytesRead will be 1337. This value also matches the `InternalHigh` parameter of the Overlapped structure when my callback is invoked.

My C++ implementation works as expected (`cbBytesRead` is usually the buffer size), so why does it fail when using C#/pinvoke?

Full source code is here: https://gist.github.com/1696375

#### Edit:

I found that by using `CreateEvent` and associating an event with my `OVERLAPPED` structure I suddenly started getting real numbers. Does `SleepEx` behave differently under .NET than C++?

Comment: Are you sure that marshaling reference to OVERLAPPED structure in .NET gives the same results as passing the pointer in C++? You can try using IntPtr and allocating unmanaged memory for OVERLAPPED.

Comment: The OVERLAPPED structure is not pinned, so its address can change, which is a violation of the rules for ReadFileEx. In fact, the OVERLAPPED goes out of scope and is therefore available for GC!